# How to perform operations on selected rows in checkbox in a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table and I want to perform some operations(suppose doing output of selected rows in alert) on the rows which the user have checked on.
Following is my approach which is failing miserably-

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Introduction</title>
        <script>
         function kro(){
            var x = document.getElementsByName('checks');
            for (var i = 0;i < x.length;i++){
              if(x[i].checked == 1)
              var selecteddata+=x[i].value+"\n";
              }
            alert(selecteddata)
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Post</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ram</td>
                    <td>Sahi hai</td>
                    <td>Ravan:No</td>
                    <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checks" id='one'/>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ravan</td>
                    <td>Kidnap done</td>
                    <td>Ram:I'll kill you</td>
                    <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checks" id='two'/>&nbsp;</td>
            </tbody>
            <p id = "check" ></p>
        
        <button onclick="kro()">
            Result
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Following is my table-
[image]

I want to perform further operations on the selected row ,in the code ,I just want to output the selected rows using alert.
How to do that?

Expected Output-

if first row is checked then

```
Ram Sahi hai    Ravan:No
```

Comment: `var selecteddata+=x[i].value+"\n";` you are defining a variable and doing `+=`, that is your issue. Define it outside of the loop

Comment: Now ,it output `undefinedon` in the alert box

Comment: sounds like you declared it wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var selecteddata+=x[i].value+"\n";` line will throw an error, So declare the variable outside the for loop. Also you need to set a value to checkbox otherwise it will so `on`

To get the content from all the `td` get the parent of the checkbox and get the `closest` `tr`. Then get `text` from each of the td and add it in a local variable of the `if` block

```js
function kro() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName('checks');
  var selecteddata = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked) {
      let _tt = '';
      x[i].closest('tr').querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(item) {
        _tt += item.textContent.trim();

      })
      selecteddata += _tt + "\n";
    }
  }
  alert(selecteddata)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>UserName</th>
      <th>Post</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ram</td>
      <td>Sahi hai</td>
      <td>Ravan:No</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" id='one' value='test1' />&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ravan</td>
      <td>Kidnap done</td>
      <td>Ram:I'll kill you</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" id='two' value='test2' />&nbsp;</td>
  </tbody>
  <p id="check"></p>
  <button onclick="kro()">
                        Result
                    </button>
```

Comment: but it outputs the value of the checkbox tag ,I want the complete row ,e.g-`Ram Sahi hai Ravan:No` printed.

Answer (score 0):

You define and concat to the variable wrong.

should be

```js
var foo = ''; // declare outside of loop
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  foo += i + '\n'  // concat to string
}
console.log(foo)  //display it
```

Other way people would do it is with an array and joining it at the end

```js
var foo = []; // declare outside of loop
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  foo.push(i)  // add to array
}
console.log(foo.join('\n'))  //display it by joining the array items
```

Comment: I don't want the index to be printed , I want the whole content of the row printed

Comment: It was showing you how to do it, it is not a copy/paste solution. lol. If you want to get the TR, than you need to select the parent TR and read the text.

Comment: Now it output `object ElementHTMLelement`, how to do that (the second part of your comment)?